# How to Pass Authorization Header in HTTP Request when using HTML5 Player (Audio tag) for security

Tags: jquery, html, security, authentication, html5-audio

i am using HTML5 audio player as follows :

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="<url>" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

Now , i want to secure my app , So i want to pass some sessionId in Header parameter in http request for mp3 .

I could not find any way to do this , Please help if anyone knows the solution .

or

Is there any other player which gives this support  ? ? ?

Comment: The URL in source is simply a GET request audio API is making. (I think). You should make an endpoint accepting a unique identifier for the mp3 file, and return the content with desired content-type (audio/mp3 in this case) if the current session is valid, whatever you may define valid as.

Comment: Yes , But  As identifier  is in get parameter , then anyone else can use same url for playing that or downloading that audio .

Comment: Not unless you validate the session. It lives on same domain?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use HTMLAudioElement and play audio from javascript instead of html directly.
Now when you use javascript you can use secured urls to fetch the audio file and provide it to the Audio Element.
This might work for you.

Comment: So what you are saying that first i should download audio file  and then provide it to Audio element  and after play i should remove that file  . Please clarify if i understood right